# IE 10 does not show textbox width and height

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5, internet-explorer-10

I have a simple TextBox with Width and Height attributes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="400" Height="100" runat="server" />
```

Locally IE 10 does show the TextBox correct in Cassini and IIS 7.5. Published on the server IE 10 ignores the properties (IE 9 and lower are ok). The web.configs are identical.

Is there a setting in the IIS or something else, where I can change this behavior?

Comment: I have been having all kinds of unexplainable problems with IE10. I know that many times setting the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html> resolved quite a few of them.

Comment: My doctype is already html. The strange thing is, that the same IE10 works on localhost with the local IIS.

Answer (score 1):

According to Scott Hanselman, ASP.NET 4.0 and 2.0 don't recognize IE 10 and cause all sorts of havok. I had the same issue as you and upgrading to .NET 4.5 worked for me, but Scott has other fixes if you don't want to upgrade.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx

Comment: But what if server was updated to v4.5 and I still have this issue?